# CSRF protection in angular js application with cross domain

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, cross-domain, csrf

My APIs are running in `api.domain.com` and frontend angular application 
 is running under `frontend.domain.com`

**CSRF implementation**

1. Enabled CORS on my `api.domain.com` and access allowed only from `frontend.domain.com`.
2. CSRF token is set in a custom response header called `X-CSRFTOKEN`
3. In Angular app, first it will make a request to get the CSRF token and 
   attach it with the request header for every `post` request

   ```
   //get CSRF token
   $http.get("http://localhost:3000/").then(function (response) {

       console.log(response.headers('X-CSRFTOKEN'));

       var request = {
           method: "POST",
           url: 'http://localhost:3000/csrftest',
           headers: {
               "CSRF-Token": response.headers('X-CSRFTOKEN')
           }
       }
       //post request with CSRF token in header
       $http(request).then(function (res) {
           console.log(res);
       }, function (err) {
           console.log(err);
       })

   }, function (err) {
       console.log("Error", err);
   });
   ```

One drawback is, I need to get CSRF token for every request so there is an extra `$http` call needed for every request because the CSRF token is changing every request (is there anyway to overcome this extra http call?)

My question is it the proper way to adding the CSRF protection in Cross-domain applications??

Comment: Do you want to DRY the code of wrapping each `POST` call to get the CSRF token call or do you want to avoid requesting each time?

Comment: I need a DRY code CSRF token but most importantly is my method of getting CSRF token correct or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Is there any way to overcome this extra HTTP call?

In my view (or as I saw as a general practice), at the start of the application, you should do the CSRF call once and your server should set a cookie containing the CSRF token (so you need to modify your server code to generate a single CSRF token for the current user session) which should be valid for the whole user session.

Then, in your Angular application, define the request interceptor, and you can read that cookie and set it as HTTP header for every POST request.

Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Cookie-to-header_token

**For example**: (using your existing code of passing the token in response header)

*Assuming, your server uses the same CSRF token everytime for the existing session.*

In your `run` block, hit the API and get the token and store that in the `localStorage`:

```
angular.module('myApp').run(function ($http) {
    // This will be executed once the application loads 
    $http.get('http://localhost:3000/').then(function (response) {
        // store the token in the local storage for further use
        localStorage.csrfToken = response.headers('X-CSRFTOKEN');
    });
});
```

Then add an interceptor and modify the POST requests to add that token:

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
        return {
            'request': function(config) {
                if (config.method === 'POST') {
                    config.headers['CSRF-Token'] = localStorage.csrfToken;
                }

                return config;
            }
        };
    });
});
```

Now your every POST request will be intercepted and the CSRF token will be set.

### I need a DRY code for CSRF token

But if you want a DRY code where you want to do an extra HTTP call for getting CSRF token before every POST request, that is also possible either using interceptors or a service.

#### Using an interceptor:

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($http, $q) {
        function doAnotherCallToGetTokenAndSetItToRequest(config) {
            var defer = $q.defer();

            $http.get("http://localhost:3000/").then(function (response) {
                config.headers['CSRF-Token'] = response.headers('X-CSRFTOKEN');
                defer.resolve(config);
            });

            return defer.promise;
        }

        return {
            'request': function(config) {
                if (config.method === 'POST') {
                    return doAnotherCallToGetTokenAndSetItToRequest(config);
                }

                return config;
            }
        };
    });
});
```

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors):

> `request`: interceptors get called with a http `config` object. The
>   function is free to modify the `config` object or create a new one. The
>   function needs to return the `config` object directly, or a promise
>   containing the `config` or a new config object.

Now, anywhere in your code, just call API's directly and the interceptor will take care of pulling a new CSRF token and setting it to the current request:

```
var request = {
    method: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/csrftest'
}

$http(request).then(function (res) {
    console.log(res);
}, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: I can't read CSRF form cookie because the API and front end application are running in different domains so thats why I am attaching CSRF token in the header

Comment: Can you modify your server code? If yes then you change your cookie domain to `domain.com` instead of `api.domain.com`.

Comment: I mean to say, if you can change your server side code where you are setting the token in the response header, instead you can set that in cookie with domain `domain.com` so that you can access that cookie in Javascript at `frontend.domain.com`

Comment: Well, I'll give you example to read token from response header

Comment: If token is changing on every request how do pass the header??

Comment: Updated the answer in case of new token for every request

Comment: Let me try  your answer

Comment: Let me know, if you stuck somewhere. I have not tried that but this should work

Comment: Error in Circular dependency found: $http <- $http <- $templateRequest <- $compile

Comment: Which version of Angular you are using?

Comment: version `1.6.4` <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>